# VBA > Ribbon > How to add large icons to menu items

Tags: xml, vba, xlsx

.xlsm > customUI > customUI.xml

When I use size="large" for the menu element below, I see the button with large icon.

```
<button id="btn" size="large" imageMso="GroupOmsInsert"/>
```

But when I put the button with atribute size="large" inside a menu, custom ribbon elements do not appear at all.

```
<menu id="S1" imageMso="TableFind" label="MyMenu">
    <button id="btn" size="large" imageMso="GroupOmsInsert"/>
</menu>
```

If delete size="large", the element appears in menu with small icon normally.

```
<menu id="S1" imageMso="TableFind" label="MyMenu">
    <button id="btn" imageMso="GroupOmsInsert"/>
</menu>
```

Is there any restriction to have large icons for menu elements?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `itemSize="normal"` or `itemSize="large"` in your `menu` element to size the items in the menu. The `size` (with a value of either `normal` or `large`) attribute determines the size of the menu button itself.

And you have to make sure to remove the `size` attribute from any buttons or other controls within the `menu` element.

```
<menu id="S1" imageMso="TableFind" label="MyMenu" size="large" itemSize="large">
    <button id="btn" imageMso="GroupOmsInsert"/>
</menu>
```